# Create deciles to group and label records where the sum of a value is the same for each decile

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, grouping, ranking, quantile

I have something similar to the following table, which is a randomly ordered list of thousands of transactions with a Customer_ID and an order_cost for each transaction.

| Customer_ID | order_cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $503 |
| 53 | $7 |
| 4 | $80 |
| 13 | $76 |
| 6 | $270 |
| 78 | $2 |
| 8 | $45 |
| 910 | $89 |
| 10 | $3 |
| 1130 | $43 |
| etc... | etc... |

I want to group the transactions by Customer_ID, aggregate the cost of all the orders into a spending column, and then create a new "decile" row that would assign a number 1-10 to each customer so that when the "spending" for all customers in a decile is added up, each decile contains 10% of all the spending.

The resulting table would look something like the table below where each ascending decile will contain fewer customers, but the total sum of "spending" for all the records in each decile group will be the same for deciles 1-10. (The actual numbers in this sample column don't actually add up, it's just the concept)

| Customer_ID | spending | Decile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | $500 | 1 |
| 3 | $700 | 1 |
| 349 | $800 | 1 |
| 23 | $1,000 | 1 |
| 64 | $2,000 | 1 |
| 718 | $2,100 | 1 |
| 3452 | $2,300 | 1 |
| 1276 | $2,600 | 2 |
| 10 | $3,000 | 2 |
| 34 | $4,000 | 2 |
| etc... | etc... | etc... |

So far I have grouped by Customer_ID, aggregated the order_cost to a spending column, ordered each customer in ascending order based on the spending column, and then partitioned all the customers into 5000 groups. From there I manually found the values for each .when statement that would result in deciles 1-10 each containing the right amount of customers so each decile has 10% of the sum of the entire spending column. It's pretty time-consuming to use trial and error to find the right bucket configuration that results in each decile having 10% of the spending column.

I'm trying to find a way to automate this process so I don't have to find the right bucketing ratio for each decile by trial and error.

This is my code so far:

```
Import pyspark.sql.functions as F
deciles = (table
                .groupBy('Customer_ID')
                .agg(F.sum('order_cost').alias('spending')).alias('a')
                .withColumn('rank', F.ntile (5000).over(W.Window.partitionBy()
                .orderBy(F.asc('spending')))) 
                .withColumn('rank', F.when(F.col('rank')<=4628, F.lit(1))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4850, F.lit(2))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4925, F.lit(3))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4965, F.lit(4))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4980, F.lit(5))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4987, F.lit(6))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4993, F.lit(7))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4997, F.lit(8))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=4999, F.lit(9))
                                     .when(F.col('rank')<=5000, F.lit(10))
                                     .otherwise (F.lit(0)))
           )

end_table = (table.alias('a').join(deciles.alias('b'), ['Customer_ID'], 'left')
            .selectExpr('a.*', 'b.rank')
             )
```